# How do I implement SAML in my application

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using a SaaS application and I want to use our own LDAP to Login to that 3rd party application. I want to provide a link to that application in my Portal. Both the applications are hosted in Cloud and are Spring based.

Please let me know where to Start and how to go about implementing SP initiated SAML.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a SAML IDP that authenticates against LDAP e.g. shibboleth.

Then you need a client side SAML stack.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

You could also look at IDaaS e.g. Auth0 or Okta.

Comment: Thanks! I have a saas app. now this client wants to integrate via SAML. Consireding the same URL will be used by other clients who would directly login to my app, how to protect my URL just for this Client who wants to SSO using his Idp?

Comment: You need two login buttons.